# linux bash, error when assigning a path in a variable to use it like target folder

Tags: bash

my script is very simple, i try to store a path in a variable then use it to copy files, the script is longer, a lot of copys, but using the same variable:

```
mainserverapp="${HOME}/Dropbox/servers/app-env-files"
cp -av "${mainserverapp}/.env*" ./
```

but i get this error:

```
cp: cannot stat '/home/.../Dropbox/servers/app-env-files/.env*': No such file or directory
```

but the folder exist if i do a 'ls '
something is happening with the variable... where is my error?

UPDATE:
i think i find it !!! the problem is the asterisk , any solution to don't copy file by file?

Comment: I don't think the shell performs globbing inside double quoted strings. `.env*` literally does not exist.

Comment: not really, i have a lot of files like this:  .env-production  .env-dev  (there are hidden linux files)

Comment: this is working, i'm gettint the files :   ls /home/myuser/Dropbox/servers/app-env-files/pelefiberadmin/.env*

Comment: a manual copy wihtout variables is working: cp -av /home/myuser/Dropbox/servers/app-env-files/pelefiberadmin/.env* ./

Comment: i think i find it !!! the problem is the asterisk , any solution?

Comment: `*` is expanded only when it is not quoted or escaped. Move it outside the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asterisk (`*`) is expanded only when it is not inside quotes and not escaped.

On `"${mainserverapp}/.env*"` only `$mainserverapp` is replaced with its value, the `*` is used as it is.

Move the asterisk outside the quotes:

```
cp -av "${mainserverapp}"/.env* ./
```

You can write it `"${mainserverapp}/.env"*` as well but it makes more sense to put inside quotes only the dynamic part, that get replaced with a value you cannot know. `.env` does not cause issues, it doesn't need to be quoted. And `.env*` represents a logical part of the expression, the files whose names start with `.env`.

Read about "Filename Expansion" in the [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: wow, you are an genius !! where you learn that things, any book ? it worked !

Comment: The documentation contains all the information you need. It is not an easy reading and it is also very long but in the end it is the source of truth. You can get the documentation of the Linux commands by using `man`. F.e `man bash` or `man ls`. Or you can read them online.